# Rails 3: Create button to run an action without page redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm very new to Rails so here goes:

I know how to make a basic for that sends the results to another page with

```
<%= form_tag "Class/Action">
# and    
<% submit_tag "Button name">
```

but what I want are a few buttons that run an action (and the page the user is on doesn't change or refresh).

Also, if you have a better alternative, here's exactly what I'm doing: A user is presented with choices and when he selects one, I want to push the choice to other clients via Juggernaut. Juggernaut is used through Rails with the command Juggernaut.publish(channel, message), and so I need to call an action that does this command, without refreshing or changing his page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `:remote => true` form and run the action via Ajax. This also gives you an easy opportunity to return either data, HTML, or JavaScript to let the user know what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there also a similar way to achieve the same effect with hyperlinks, as opposed to a form button?

Comment: Same `:remote` option; here's an [example that toggles a property](http://buckybits.blogspot.com/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html) I wrote for some co-workers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the :remote => true in your form_tag.  Here's an example...

```
<%= form_for(@folder, :remote => true) do |field| %>
    <%= field.label :Name %>
    <%= field.text_field :Name, :placeholder => "New Folder" %>
    <%= field.submit "Create", :disable_with => "Saving..." %>
<% end %>
```